# can't use CreateProcess in Child process using simulating fork code on Windows 7 based on ZwCreateProcess

Tags: windows, windows-7, process, operating-system, fork

I try to simulate fork using `ZwCreateProcess`. It seems to work when I
use some simple test program. But when I try to create a new process
using `CreateProcess` API in the forked child process. The child process
paused for a while (and so did parent process) and then crashed.
Could you give me some hint?

The following are the test code and fork reference implementation code:

```c
/*****************************************************/
Test program code fragment:

if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
    printf("fork error");
    return -1;
}

if (pid == 0) {
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    //Child process will pause here for a while and then crash.
    if(CreateProcess(_T("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe"), NULL, NULL, NULL,
                      FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
        CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
    }else{
        //  fputs("cann't create process", fp2);
    }
}else{
    //Parent code
}

/*****************************************************************************************************/
```

And the following is what I used the reference fork implementation code from internet:

```c
int win32_fork()
{
    HANDLE hProcess = 0;
    HANDLE hThread = 0;
    BOOL bReturn;
    InheritAll();
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = {sizeof oa};


    ZwCreateProcess(&hProcess, PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, &oa,
                       0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    CONTEXT context = {CONTEXT_FULL
                         | CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS
                         | CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT};
    ZwGetContextThread(NtCurrentThread(), &context);
    context.Eip = ULONG(child);

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    ZeroMemory( &mbi, sizeof( mbi ) );
    ZwQueryVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), PVOID(context.Esp),
                         MemoryBasicInformation, &mbi, sizeof mbi,
                         0);

    USER_STACK stack = {0, 0, PCHAR(mbi.BaseAddress) + mbi.RegionSize,
                           mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.AllocationBase};
    CLIENT_ID cid;
    ZwCreateThread(&hThread, THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, &oa,
                      hProcess, &cid, &context, &stack, TRUE);
    THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION tbi;
    ZeroMemory( &tbi, sizeof( tbi ) );
    ZwQueryInformationThread(NtCurrentThread(),
                                ThreadBasicInformation,
                                &tbi, sizeof tbi, 0);
    PNT_TIB tib = (PNT_TIB)tbi.TebBaseAddress;
    ZwQueryInformationThread(hThread, ThreadBasicInformation,
                                &tbi, sizeof tbi, 0);
    ZwWriteVirtualMemory(hProcess, tbi.TebBaseAddress,
                            &tib->ExceptionList, sizeof tib->ExceptionList,
                            0);
    InformCsrss(hProcess, hThread,
               ULONG(cid.UniqueProcess), ULONG(cid.UniqueThread));

    ZwResumeThread(hThread, 0);
    ZwClose(hThread);
    ZwClose(hProcess);
    return int(cid.UniqueProcess);
}
```

Comment: Nobody can diagnose a "it crashed" problem.  You need to tell us what you know.

Comment: I don't know how to describe the exact problem. Win7 just prompted a dialog which asked whether to send a report to Microsoft.

Comment: From what I can tell, the child process isn't getting to initialize itself normally.  It wouldn't be too surprising if as a result it is unable to use some Win32 functions, such as CreateProcess.  Try using ZwCreateProcess instead.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: <strike>do you mean `NtCreateProcess()` by a chance? `Zw*()` counterpart is already being used in the question.</strike> Oh, I see, the initial snippet used `CreateProcess()` only.